# How to add calculated rows below each row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe_1` as such:

```
Index   Time          Label
0       0.000 ns      Segment 1
1       2.749 sec     baseline
2       3.459 min     begin test
3       7.009 min     end of test
```

And I would like to add multiple new rows in between each of `dataframe_1`'s rows, where the Time column for each new row would add an additional minute until reaching `dataframe_1`'s next row's time (and corresponding Label). For example, the above table should ultimately look like this:

```
Index     Time               Label
0         0.000 ns           Segment 1
1         2.749 sec          baseline
2         00:01:02.749000    baseline + 1min
3         00:02:02.749000    baseline + 2min
4         00:03:02.749000    baseline + 3min
5         3.459 min          begin test
6         00:04:27.540000    begin test + 1min
7         00:05:27.540000    begin test + 2min
8         00:06:27.540000    begin test + 3min
9         7.009 min          end of test
```

Using `Timedelta` type via `pd.to_timedelta()` is perfectly fine.

I thought the best way to do this would be to break up each row of `dataframe_1` into its own dataframe, and then adding rows for each added minute, and then `concat`ing the dataframes back together. However, I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

Should I use a nested for-loop to [first] iterate over the rows of `dataframe_1` and then [second] iterate over a counter so I can create new rows with added minutes?

I was previously not splitting up the individual rows into new dataframes, and I was doing the second iteration like this:

```
    baseline_row = df_legend[df_legend['Label'] == 'baseline']
    [baseline_index] = baseline_row.index
    baseline_time = baseline_row['Time']

    interval_mins = 1
    new_time = baseline_time + pd.Timedelta(minutes=interval_mins)

    cutoff_time_np = df_legend.iloc[baseline_row.index + 1]['Time']
    cutoff_time = pd.to_timedelta(cutoff_time_np)
    
    while new_time.reset_index(drop=True).get(0) < cutoff_time.reset_index(drop=True).get(0):

        new_row = baseline_row.copy()
        new_row['Label'] = f'minute {interval_mins}'
        new_row['Time'] = baseline_time + pd.Timedelta(minutes=interval_mins)
        new_row.index = [baseline_index + interval_mins - 0.5]

        df_legend = df_legend.append(new_row, ignore_index=False)
        df_legend = df_legend.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
        pdb.set_trace()

        interval_mins += 1
        new_time = baseline_time + pd.Timedelta(minutes=interval_mins)
```

But since I want to do this for each row in the original `dataframe_1`, then I was thinking to split it up into separate dataframes and put it back together. I'm just not sure what the best way is to do that, especially since pandas is apparently very slow if iterating over the rows.

I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Methodologically, your question is the same as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005322/add-a-calculated-row-below-each-row-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: The method is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005322/add-a-calculated-row-below-each-row-in-a-pandas-data-frame

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes thank you for that link. I do believe my situation is a bit more complicated, however. If you understand a reasonable solution, I'd really appreciate a more targeted answer below.

Comment: It's too complex. I think you have to use a loop anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might faster than your solution.

```
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
df['counts'] = df.Time.diff().apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()) / 60
df['counts'] = np.floor(df.counts.shift(-1)).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.drop(columns='Index', inplace=True)

df

             Time        Label  counts
0        00:00:00    Segment 1       0
1 00:00:02.749000     baseline       3
2 00:03:27.540000   begin test       3
3 00:07:00.540000  end of test       0
```

Then use `iterrows` to get your desire output.

```
new_df = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    val = row.counts
    if val == 0:
        new_df.append(row)
    else:
        new_df.append(row)
        new_row = row.copy()
        label = row.Label
        for i in range(val):
            new_row = new_row.copy()
            new_row.Time += pd.Timedelta('1 min')
            new_row.Label = f'{label} + {i+1}min'
            new_df.append(new_row)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
new_df

             Time              Label  counts
0        00:00:00          Segment 1       0
1 00:00:02.749000           baseline       3
1 00:01:02.749000    baseline + 1min       3
1 00:02:02.749000    baseline + 2min       3
1 00:03:02.749000    baseline + 3min       3
2 00:03:27.540000         begin test       3
2 00:04:27.540000  begin test + 1min       3
2 00:05:27.540000  begin test + 2min       3
2 00:06:27.540000  begin test + 3min       3
3 00:07:00.540000        end of test       0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting `*** KeyError: "['Index'] not found in axis"`. I even get this if I do `df.drop(columns='Index', inplace=True, axis=1)`. Apparently `Index` doesn't count as a column?

Comment: @Raj Your sample dataframe has `Index` column, but you can try to delete that line it will work anyway.

Comment: I deleted the drop index line and your elegant solution now works quite well. Thank you! One change I was trying to unsuccessfully make is that I don't want to have a new row added if the very next row (from the original `dataframe_1`) is going to be within a minute of time away —so `"baseline + 3min"` @3:02.749 wouldn't exist because it's within a minute of `"begin test"` @3:27.540.

Comment: @Raj Try this snipe on new_df.  `s = new_df.Time.astype('timedelta64[m]')` and 
`to_filter = s.shift(-1).eq(s)  & (new_df.Label.apply(lambda x: 'baseline' in x))` then `new_df[~to_filter]`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you converted *Time* column from "number unit" format to a string
representation of the time. Something like:

```
               Time        Label
Index                           
0      00:00:00.000    Segment 1
1      00:00:02.749     baseline
2      00:03:27.540   begin test
3      00:07:00.540  end of test
```

Then, to get your result:

1. Compute *timNxt* - the *Time* column shifted by 1 position and converted
   to *datetime*:

   ```
   timNxt = pd.to_datetime(df.Time.shift(-1))
   ```
2. Define the following "replication" function:

   ```
   def myRepl(row):
       timCurr = pd.to_datetime(row.Time)
       timNext = timNxt[row.name]
       tbl = [[timCurr.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'), row.Label]]
       if pd.notna(timNext):
           n = (timNext - timCurr) // np.timedelta64(1, 'm') + 1
           tbl.extend([ [(timCurr + np.timedelta64(i, 'm')).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'),
               row.Label + f' + {i}min'] for i in range(1, n)])
       return pd.DataFrame(tbl, columns=row.index)
   ```
3. Apply it to each row of your *df* and concatenate results:

   ```
   result = pd.concat(df.apply(myRepl, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
   ```

The result is:

```
              Time              Label
0  00:00:00.000000          Segment 1
1  00:00:02.749000           baseline
2  00:01:02.749000    baseline + 1min
3  00:02:02.749000    baseline + 2min
4  00:03:02.749000    baseline + 3min
5  00:03:27.540000         begin test
6  00:04:27.540000  begin test + 1min
7  00:05:27.540000  begin test + 2min
8  00:06:27.540000  begin test + 3min
9  00:07:00.540000        end of test
```

The resulting DataFrame has *Time* column also as *string*, but at
least the fractional part of second has 6 digits everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately that is giving me an error `dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 2.749 sec`. Here's the [full traceback](https://paste.ee/p/kOVfU).

Comment: If "number unit" refers to "2.749 sec", then no I haven't formatted it like this, this is actually how I receive the data.

Comment: I suppose that you left "time unit" format (as you wrote  "2.749 sec"). But my code works on the assumption that *Time* column has been reformatted to "hh:mm:ss.ddd" format, just as at the beginning of my answer. Reformat this column as I wrote and my code should work.

Comment: The error occurs in the line `timNxt = pd.to_datetime(df.Time.shift(-1))`, which can be seen in the full traceback.

Comment: The most likely reason is that you didn't reformat *Time* column. You should remove the "unit" part and leave the content in "hh:mm:ss.ddd" format.